# Getting node-sass error while doing npm install inside docker container in windows WSL

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install, node-sass

I am trying to setup a laravel project in my windows setup via WSL and i am using WSL. now the issue is, when i do npm install i am getting the following error and i have tried different type of solutions but nothing is working. Any quick help would appriciable

[image]

please let me know if any additional detail required to solve this. i will provide the same

current version on my WSL
node - 21
npm - 10
nvm - 0.39.0

Here is the docker file also

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
```

RUN sed -i 's/stable/updates/stable-security/updates/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/pdftk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre
RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libgmp-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libtidy-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libpspell-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-gnutls-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libldap2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libc-client-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libkrb5-dev
RUN apt-get install -y librecode-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libsnmp-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libenchant-dev
RUN apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y python2.7
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./pdftk/pdftk.jar /usr/share/pdftk/
COPY ./pdftk/commons-lang3.jar /usr/share/java/
COPY ./pdftk/bcprov-1.58.jar /usr/share/java/

COPY ./pdftk/pdftk /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/pdftk

RUN apt-get clean

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gmp
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl

RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp snmp soap gd enchant recode curl tidy 
opcache pspell xmlrpc ldap bz2 imap dba intl xml mbstring zip pdo_mysql 
gmp gd bcmath ctype json tokenizer exif mysqli calendar

RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | 
php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN pecl install imagick mongodb

RUN echo "extension=imagick.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini && 
echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.17.0
RUN mkdir $HOME/.nvm && 
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash && 
chmod +x $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && 
. $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && 
nvm install --latest-npm "$NODE_VERSION" && 
nvm alias default "$NODE_VERSION" && 
nvm use default && 
DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION=$(nvm version default) && 
ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs && 
ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/node && 
ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

RUN npm install gulp -g

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

Answer (score 0):

Well, the build is failing because your container doesn't have `python2`. This suggests to me that you are trying to build an older version of node-sass.  If there is not a good reason for that, my first suggestion is that you build *at least* a newer version, if not the latest.

Then, I found that I was able to build node-sass with the following dependencies on alpine:

- python3
- make
- g++

This is accomplished on alpine with `apk add --no-cache python3 make g++`

Other package managers will be different.

Without seeing your Dockerfile, that's about all I can give you.  If you *absolutely must* use this version of node-sass, you will need to use an older base container that will allow you to install python2, and this will mean an older version of node as well most likely.  Finally, I recommend you use `yarn` instead of NPM.  I find it to be easier to read the error output, and friendlier in general.

Edit:
Here is a working Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:21-alpine3.17
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++ && \
yarn global add node-sass
```

Of course this container is fairly useless, but it shows that the build works with these dependencies.

My advice holds for your php version as well - unless you have a good reason to run 7.2, you should update to 8.0 (minimum non-EOL version) or 8.2.

Comment: i tried upgrading the node-sass as welll but still got the same error and then i tried using sass also but still the same and i have python 2.7 installed on my system but still getting this issue. I am sharing the docker file also for your reference

Comment: You need python 2 *in the container* not on your system.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your responses but finally i got the solution. I was running the project inside WSL docker. I just make the container down and then make it up again and then i ran npm install and it worked.

- sudo docker-compose down
- sudo docker-compose up -d
- sudo docker-compose exec your_image_name bash
- npm install

Then it worked. Thanks

=======